# Making all checkboxes mandatory with submit button going to a URL

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How do I create a form with all checkboxes being mandatory and a submit button going to a URL?
I've searched all over and all the examples just do one or the other. I've found samples that can make checkboxes mandatory, and samples that make submit button go to URL, but not both.

Help.

Comment: its always a good idea if you can provide some code that you have worked, where you got stuck and any errors that you may have obtained. help us, help you.

Comment: <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="myCheck">
    <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="myCheck">
  <input type="submit" name="myCheck" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  } else {
     text.style.display = "do it again";
  }
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far...

```
 <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="myCheck">
    <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="myCheck">
  <input type="submit" name="myCheck" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  } else {
     text.style.display = "do it again";
  }
}
</script>
```